# UK Standard Visitor visa confusion -- 'Other' or 'Business related' for attending a training/workshop as a researcher?

Tags: uk, business-travel

I am going to attend a **training/workshop** at a very renowned research intergovernmental institution in the United Kingdom.

My entire visit and all expenses will be **entirely covered by my employer** in my country of residence. I am attending the training event on the request of my employer to excel at my responsibilities.

I am quite confused about the "Reason" I should choose in the window below:

[image]

It is true that I am employed in my country of residence, but I am not really sure if the word '**business**' matches my situation. Because I am a **researcher** in academia (at a research institute) and I will go to the UK for a training in another research institute.

**My questions**:

- Should I simply choose "Business" and then on the next page choose "Business-related training"? Or should I choose "**Other**" and then explain why I am going to the UK in the text field that comes up?
- Choosing "Business-related training" opens up another set of questions asking me: **Will you be paid for any of your business activities while in the UK?** Should I answer yes to this? My employer will pay for all the expenses arising from the trip and also will pay the training fees, food, registration, etc. Should the answer to this question then be yes or no?

I have already contacted 'UK Visas and Immigration' and their simple answer was: "We cannot help you with that, you should choose the correct one for yourself"!

Answer (score 4):

> I am quite confused about the "Reason" I should choose in the window
>   below

Based on what you wrote, you can select "Other" and when the description text box opens...

- give a brief description and mention that the event's glossy (along with your registration/invitation info) is
  included in your evidence bundle;
- cite the *exact* paragraph (and subparagraph if there is one) from
  [Appendix 3 of Appendix V of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) that best covers what you
  will be doing (an important step for your case and part of best practices for all applications)

You have 500 characters which should be enough, but can continue to a separate sheet if need be (this is unwise because it invites the conclusion that your application is complex).

---

> Will you be paid for any of your business activities while in the UK?
>   Should I answer yes to this?

If you are travelling on a corporate expense account (as I understand it), then the answer is no, you will not be paid. The rules allow a person to recoup their expenditures and even to receive a small honorarium.

You will have to make the relevant disclosures in this question...

[image]

---

> I have already contacted 'UK Visas and Immigration' and their simple
>   answer was: "We cannot help you with that, you should choose the
>   correct one for yourself"!

This is normal and no cause for alarm. Their instructions are to feed back what is published on their site and nothing more, and they are not supposed to delve into anything to the extent where the person becomes a "*particular individual*" as defined by the 1999 Act.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am just worried that the 'wrong' (between 'Other' and 'Business') choice might render my application weak in the end. You see, it is exactly the very Appendix V that has perplexed me. `Work-related training` is precisely sectioned under 'Business'. In that Appendix, sections 23 and 24 seem to reflect what I will be doing in the UK, but then they are written under 'Business'. I do not really know if the choice between 'Other' and 'Business-related training' is that sensitive. Can they simply reject my application because of that?